# make redis query result readable

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I am use redis-cli to query redis.I want the result more readable.Now,I will see something like this.
[image]
It seems that I use the worng encoding way. How can I change my command to make it readable.
For example,I want to read a hashset with key abc.
Now I use `hgetall abc`.Should I add other params to it?